# PlayFramework Application 2.7.x Custom Error Page for each type of Error

Tags: scala, playframework

When a controller returns a InternalServerError, I want a custom page to render the error messages in a user friendly way.

I found this documentation on the internet

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal

Now I understand that the above URL is no longer valid for Playframework 2.7. I searched more and found this

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaErrorHandling

But this is not the same as the older error handler. In the past I could have handled `onHandlerNotFound` and `onBadRequest` and `onInternalServerError` but now I all I can handle is `onServerError`

With the new approach of extending from `HttpErrorHandler` How can I send my response to a custom error page depending on each type of error.

Edit: Maybe the question is not clear. In the error handler I want to send the errors to a custom error page. This was shown in the example of play 2.3.x where I could do

```
object Global extends GlobalSettings {
  override def onError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable) = {
    Future.successful(InternalServerError(
      views.html.errorPage(ex)
    ))
  }
}
```

I want to do something similar in Play 2.7.x and beyond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide a custom error page for an unhandled exception, as you could in Play 2.3 using `onError` method, in Play 2.7 implement `ErrorHandler.onServerError` method.

For Bad Request and Not Found and other client errors, there is `ErrorHandler.onClientError` method to implement, that allows returning custom templates based on the status code.

```
import javax.inject.Singleton
import play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler
import play.api.http.Status._
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent._

@Singleton
class ErrorHandler extends DefaultHttpErrorHandler {

  override def onClientError(request: RequestHeader, statusCode: Int, message: String): Future[Result] = {
    statusCode match {
      case NOT_FOUND => Future.successful(NotFound(views.html.notFound()))
      case BAD_REQUEST => Future.successful(BadRequest(views.html.badRequest()))
      case _ => super.onClientError(request, statusCode, message)
    }
  }

  override def onServerError(request: RequestHeader, ex: Throwable): Future[Result] = {
    Future.successful(
      InternalServerError(views.html.errorPage(ex))
    )
  }

}
```

Comment: But this is still not what I want. I want to render a custom error page. In the previous example they could do `InternalServerError(views.html.errorPage(exceptions))`. This way all the exceptions will go to a custom template where I can render the error message.

Comment: It still doesn't do what I want. because I want a custom error page for each type or error. Now every error will go to a same page. How can I capture each and every type of error and then route it to its corresponding page.

Comment: Could you add the errors you want to handle to the question? You can also post your solution in Play 2.3 and I’ll convert it to Play 2.7.

Comment: I want to handle `onBadRequest` and `onInternalServerError` on `onHandlerNotFound ` separately. So basically, I should be able to trap these errors in my class derived from HTTPErrorHandler and then route them to their respective templates.

Comment: Please, correct me if I’m wrong. You want to have a custom play template for 404 page not found, 400 bad request, and 500 Internal Server Error. Right?

Comment: I've updated my answer with those 3 custom play templates.